# Why is silicon absorbing visible light?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, light-emitting-diodes

Here it is shown that silicon absorbs visible light:

[image: Absorption]

but the band gap energy for direct transitions is 3.6 eV which does not match to this absorption coefficient. Instead, the band gap energy for an indirect transition is 1.12 eV. Hence, I assume, the visible light must excite silicon through indirect transitions.
Is that correct? If so, how does this work? Why is visible light being able to lift an electron from the valence up into the conduction band?

[image: Band gaps]

[Source](https://books.google.de/books?id=-JpYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=silicon%20indirect%20band%20gap%203.6%20ev%20momentum&source=bl&ots=uXR5diA735&sig=ACfU3U3831rfWN5ZgM8RxsyvypMJJBJ7Fg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDg7PYvI7kAhUEI1AKHYMtDwQQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=silicon%20indirect%20band%20gap%203.6%20ev%20momentum&f=false)

Comment: Because phonon-assisted processes allow an electron to go from the top of the valence band to the bottom of the conduction band (not via the steps shown in your second figure, but directly over).

Comment: @user47014 Afaik this is pure silica

Comment: @JonCuster Where does this phonon come from when the impinging light only provides the band gap energy?

Comment: The lattices has phonons flying around already since the temperature is above 0K. In Raman scattering, one gets both photons back at higher energy (having absorbed a phonon) and lower energy (having generated a phonon).

Comment: Really? So this means the working principle of a (silicon-)photodiode is mainly based on phonons?

Comment: I highly recommend the book 'Optical Processes in Semiconductors' by Jacques Pankove. Old but good. He devotes 50+ pages to the many and various ways photons can be absorbed in direct and indirect semiconductors. But, yes, phonon-assisted absorption is a big one.

Comment: thanks, will check out if I have access to it. I stumbled over a statement that doped silica has a band gap energy of about 25 meV. The source is in another language but I think it is also given here on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5337967/

Comment: Note that 'silica' and 'silicon' are two different things (one is SiO2, the other is Si). And, yes, they introduced a degenerately doped impurity band.